# Why does Django with sqlite not insert unique constraint into the database schema?

Tags: django, sqlite, constraints, schema, unique

I am starting to use Django with sqlite and I want to impose a simple unique constraint on the combination of two fields in a table. To this end, I use Django's UniqueConstraint class. However, to my surprise, the constraint is not inserted in to the tables schema in the database. My Django model looks like follows:

```
from django.db import models

class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fruit_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='', blank=True, null=False)
    fruit_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, null=False)
    class Meta:
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['fruit_type', 'fruit_name'], name='unique_fruit_type_name')
        db_table = 'fruit'
```

After migration, I check the schema in the database by executing:

```
select sql from sqlite_master where type='table';
```

The result, for the table in question, reads:

```
CREATE TABLE "fruit" ("fruit_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY"fruit_type" varchar(64) NOT NULL), "fruit_name" varchar(128) NOT NULL
```

I was expecting to get:

```
CREATE TABLE "fruit" ("fruit_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY"fruit_type" varchar(64) NOT NULL), "fruit_name" varchar(128) NOT NULL, UNIQUE (fruit_type, fruit_name)
```

Where did the UNIQUE-clause go? Is it not supposed to be in the schema?

Answer (score 4):

You write the constraint directly in the `Meta` class which has no effect. You instead need to write it in a list on the attribute [`constraints` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#constraints) in the `Meta` class:

```python
from django.db import models

class Fruit(models.Model):
    fruit_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    fruit_type = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='', blank=True, null=False)
    fruit_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='', blank=True, null=False)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['fruit_type', 'fruit_name'], name='unique_fruit_type_name')
        ]
        db_table = 'fruit'
```

> **Note**: Make sure to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` after making these changes.

Comment: Yes! That did the trick. Now I get 
`CREATE TABLE "fruit" ("fruit_id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "fruit_name" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "fruit_type" varchar(64) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "unique_fruit_type_name" UNIQUE ("fruit_type", "fruit_name"))`